# any idea why x gets to 0 and then nan

Tags: c, user-defined-functions

I have made a new `#define g(x)` that doesn't work as expected when I print x and num is number int greater(>) of 2

I tried to print my `#define g(x)` with no success

Code below:

```
#define g(x,num) 1/3*(2 * x + (num / x))
#define f(x,num) x*x - num
#define var 1E-12 //(1E-12 = 10^-12)

double x;
int i;
double num;

double srt(double num) {
     x = num; 


    for(i; abs(f(x,num)) > var ;i++) {


     x = g(x,num);
      printf ("x: %f\n", x);

                        }   
    printf ("counter %d\n", i);             
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("give number\n");
    scanf("%lf", &num);
    printf ("your number is num: %lf\n", num);
    printf("srt : %lf", srt(num));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show a complete program please?  we need to be able to see how `sqrt` is called

Comment: `1/3` will evaluate to `0`.

Comment: thanks Osiris i've come to the conclusion that 1/3 has to be 1.0/3.0 thanks a lot

Comment: Somebody make an answer please. @Osiris ?

Comment: Don't use macros for such cases. Make `f` and `g` a genuine function, perhaps a `static inline` one. Then read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Your code is "wrong" if used as `g(3.0+z)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your macro:

```
#define g(x,num) 1/3*(2 * x + (num / x))
```

In C `1/3` is evaluated as integer division and will therefore always evaluate to `0`. To solve this problem at least one literal should be made `double` instead of `int`:

```
#define g(x,num) 1.0/3.0*(2.0*x + (num/x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another problem

**int math**

Code uses `int abs(int)` when `double fabs(double)` is needed.

```
// for(i; abs(f(x,num)) > var ;i++) {
for(i; fabs(f(x,num)) > var ;i++) {
```

---

Good compilers well enabled often warn about such easy-to-detect problems - including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242359/2410359).  Not using tools well is the key problem here.

Save time, **enable all warnings**.